# Infer template argument for pointer to function

Tags: c++, templates

For the following code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <class T>
inline auto foo(const T* A)
{
    return A[0];
}

template <class T>
struct impl
{
    template <typename F>
    static auto bar(const T& A, F func)
    {
        return func(&A[0]);
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<size_t> A = {2, 3, 4};
    std::cout << impl<decltype(A)>::bar(A, &foo) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I get (with C++14 using clang on macOS) that

```
main.cpp:23:18: error: no matching function for call to 'bar'
    std::cout << impl<decltype(A)>::bar(A, &foo) << std::endl;
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:14:17: note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'F'
    static auto bar(const T& A, F func)
                ^
1 error generated.
```

My question is: *Why? How can I fix it?*

Answer (score 3):

`foo` is the name of a template, not the name of a function.  `bar` requires a type, not a template.  Fortunately lambda expressions are a fast easy way to wrap generic function into an object type that can be known and do the dispatch for you.  That would give you

```
std::cout << impl<decltype(A)>::bar(A, [](const auto& var){ return foo(var); }) 
          << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is actually from `foo` not from `impl`. `foo` is a template and you will an error also for:

```
auto x = &foo;

source>:23:15: error: unable to deduce 'auto' from '& foo'
   23 |     auto x = &foo;
      |               ^~~
<source>:23:15: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter 'auto'
```

I am not suggesting this a the "right" solution, it is just to show how in principle you can get a pointer to the right instantiation of `foo`:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<size_t> A = {2, 3, 4};
    std::cout << impl<decltype(A)>::bar(A,
        static_cast<size_t(*)(const decltype(A)::value_type*)>(&foo)) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Or the more readable (thanks to @StoryTeller):

```
int main()
{

    std::vector<size_t> A = {2, 3, 4};
    //auto x = &foo<decltype(A)::value_type>;
    std::cout << impl<decltype(A)>::bar(A,&foo<decltype(A)::value_type>) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Note that `gcc` does emit the same error as for the original. This appears to be a [bug in gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=97999). Removing the `//` from the line above magically makes it compile also with gcc even though `x` is not used. The bug seems to be fixed in gcc-trunk: https://godbolt.org/z/noqGEP (see also https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54111).

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, thank a lot! Could you comment how this solution compares to the lambda function suggested by @NathanOliver ?

Comment: If we are gonna spell out the argument type involved, `&foo<decltype(A)::value_type>` is a whole lot more readable. And now it doesn't even need a cast (even a C++-style one)

Comment: @StoryTeller similar error: https://godbolt.org/z/vnPna7. I don't really understand it...

Comment: @TomdeGeus Nathans solution is a lot more flexible because you don't have to explicitly spell out the type but rather let `auto` and overload resolution do that for you.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica I liked your suggestion, but when I was trying it in my production code I get the error in the OP on the latest Ubuntu on my GitHub-CI (not on OSx nor on MSVS).

Comment: @TomDeGeus see edit. I dont know msvc, but I got the same error with gcc (not with clang). I believe it is a bug in gcc and adding the line `auto x = &foo<decltype(A)::value_type>;` magically fixes the error (even though `x` is not used)

Comment: Thanks @largest_prime_is_463035818 !

Comment: @TomDeGeus I remember a question about just that issue, but it is hard to find. If I find it I'll let you know

Comment: @TomdeGeus - I'm guessing GCC? I encountered this bug myself in the past (here's a report, though not by me https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=97999). I was hoping it'd by fixed by GCC 10. Judging by the godbolt link... seems not.

Comment: Here's a report from 2012 https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54111 ... oh well

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica It seems to be fixed in the trunk: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54111

Comment: @TomdeGeus indeed: https://godbolt.org/z/noqGEP I'll add that to the answer

Answer (score 1):

This should work (without lambda):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <class T>
auto foo(const T* A)
{
    return A[0];
}

template <class T>
struct impl
{
    template <typename F>
    static auto bar(const T& A, F func)
    {
        return func(&A[0]);
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<size_t> A = {20, 3, 4};

    std::cout << impl<decltype(A)>::bar(A, &foo<size_t>) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

but [gcc fails](https://godbolt.org/z/qjTbhq) for some reason (clang and msvc are fine with that).